# How to handle POST request responses in Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

It's perfect til this part, all I can do here is displaying `response.body().toString()`, how can I get String systemDate and String token as a response and save them in my app? I tried with POSTMAN, there is no issue with the response, I just don't know how to get it

Comment: what response u r getting in postman ?

Comment: @chandanicpatel json response with "systemDate" and "token"

Comment: InitPost  class will contain the fields u r getting in response , please paste your response so i can guide you

Comment: `response.body();` will give you the response as a InitPost object in `onResponse` method.Please post postman response

Answer (score 0):

your response POJO should contain all the fields you are expecting in response

```
class InitPost {


    @SerializedName("appVersion")
    @Expose
    var versionName: String? = null

    @SerializedName("deviceName")
    @Expose
    var manufacturer: String? = null

    @SerializedName("systemDate")
    @Expose
    var systemDate: String? = null

    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    var token: String? = null

}
```

Comment: but I'm not getting appVersion and deviceName as response, just systemDate and token ? could this be an issue?

Comment: Just match your json response from postman to POJO class, it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Create one more DTO that contains your fields.

```
    @SerializedName("systemDate")
    @Expose
    val systemDate: String? = null

    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    val token: String? = null
```

Then change your `Call` generic type from `Call<InitPost>` to `Call<`NewPOJO`>`. In your `onResponse` Callback use `response.body()` and you will get `NewPOJO` object

Comment: and how should I access their getters in my onResponse method?

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu change your Call generic type from Call<InitPost> to Call<NewPOJO>